# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cloudinary' not found

Tags: php, cloudinary

When I try to upload a image in cloudinary am getting **"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cloudinary' not found"** this error in my config file.

And my config file contains:

```
<?php

\Cloudinary::config(array( 
    "cloud_name" => 'dnxxxxxxd', 
    "api_key" => '981xxxxxxxxxxx0', 
    "api_secret" => '0wlNxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx10g'
));
?>
```

Why I'm getting this ??

Comment: What version of the SDK are you running? It looks like PHPv1 supports this syntax, so best to check which version you have installed.

Comment: As above, the most likely reason for this error is if the SDK isn't installed in the environment of your PHP file - how are you including it in your actual PHP file and how was it installed to your project?

Answer (score 1):

## 05 2021

I hope you found the solution. If not try this

### Cloudinary PHP SDK v2.x.

https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php
**Note**: cloudinary_php require PHP 5.6. If for some ready you get the error try the version 1.x (legacy)

### Cloudinary PHP (legacy)

https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/tree/support/1.x